# Mellin Transform of the Tan Function

Tags: calculus

It is clear that 
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{8 x}{\pi ^2 (2 k-1)^2-4 x^2}=\tan (x).$$
Could you please calculate the Mellin transform? I got
$$i \left(2^s-2\right) \left(-\frac{1}{2} (i \pi )\right)^s \zeta (1-s) \sec \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right),$$
but it seems I am wrong...

Comment: What do you mean with the Mellin transform of $\tan(x)$ ? $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \tan(x)dx$ obviously doesn't converge, so you have to explain how to regularize it. For example $\tanh(x)- 1= \frac{-2e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}} =- 2\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-2nx}$ so that $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}(\tanh(x)- 1)dx = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n (2n)^{-s}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-x}dx = 2^{-s}(1-(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s))\Gamma(s)$

Comment: I meant $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ so that $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} (\tanh(x)-1)dx= 2^{-s}(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) \Gamma(s)$, and if you find a way to regularize it $$\mathcal{M}[\tan(x)-1](s) = \mathcal{M}[\tan(ix)-1](s) = (-i)^{-s}\mathcal{M}[\tan(x)-1](s) = e^{-i \pi s/2}2^{-s}(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) \Gamma(s)$$

Comment: I believe that there was a typo in your comment @user1952009, the right is $$\mathcal{M}[\tan(x)-1](s) = \mathcal{M}[\tan(ix)-1](s) = (-i)^{-s}\mathcal{M}[\tanh(x)-1](s).$$

Comment: @user243301 yes but this isn't the point

Comment: @user243301 what do you mean ? And I think @ capea played with some formal series and contour integrals and residues to get $\zeta(1-s)$. By the way you should look at how the functional equation appears formally from the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) applied to $(1-e^{2i \pi s}) \Gamma(s) \zeta(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty+\int_{2i\pi+\infty}^{2i\pi-\infty} \frac{e^{sv}}{e^{e^v}-1}dv$ this contour integral  being the same as https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#Par_une_int.C3.A9grale_de_contour with $u = e^v$

Comment: With respect the typo I say only that the right last identity is for $tanh(x)-1$, the other calculations are rights, but I don't know nothing abut reguralisations. I was interested in these calculations because seems to me of a kind about one that I was reading in the Wikipedia article for Riesz function (since Riez function satisfies a special condition with respect a series, and one knows how calculate the Mellin transform of $xe^{-x}$, then I was reading this post to know your calculations). I copy your last comment. Many thanks @user1952009